# Is there a way in Javascript to set optional properties to default values?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Look this example:

```
interface Options {
    name: string;
    age?: number;
    fn?: () => Promise<any>;
}

const defaultOptions = {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 18,
    fn: () => Promise.resolve(undefined)
};

function newWay({ name, age, fn }: Options = { ...defaultOptions }) {
    console.log('newWay, name:', name);
    console.log('newWay, age:', age);
    console.log('newWay, fn:', fn);
    return;
}

newWay();

newWay({name: "Alice"});
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=3&pln=22&pc=25#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM7IDeAUMmciHALYQBcyeYUoA5gNynlwsQD89IAK5UARtA7lkMEP2QAKAJTIAvAD5kABSjYqwPBAA8cEAE9VHAL7FiCXI2QATCPEEAbMBix2VRTmUo09ADkAELYIkEANH7I3HTIAIwAHNGS0vSKKupaOnoQAHRQEHjYrgBuEHKCIE4woBAOCsQWHMQw1QheIBQQAO4A6nAmcoQU1BCRsTyT0sgW9J44+D6j+Wu1cG4emEsEFkokkrb4pQWu2CxyQSB9gyaTAXRRYzQKEuTHJa5nF1c3A0NJnFaM84m8Yp9TvlzpdrrdAVIQCCZiBwZIimBBFAQJZrP87opWvihiNHvQAEQAQVcwCQ5P2bCAA)

The log is:

```
[LOG]: "newWay, name:",  "Bob" 
[LOG]: "newWay, age:",  18 
[LOG]: "newWay, fn:",  () => Promise.resolve(undefined) 
[LOG]: "newWay, name:",  "Alice" 
[LOG]: "newWay, age:",  undefined 
[LOG]: "newWay, fn:",  undefined
```

Is there a way I can set the default `age` when not specified?

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK removing the outer `Options` and `defaultOptions` identifiers, you can put the logic all in the argument list:

```
function newWay({
    name = 'Bob',
    age = 18,
    fn = () => Promise.resolve()
}: {
    name?: string,
    age?: number,
    fn?: () => Promise<any>
} = {}) {
    console.log('newWay, name:', name);
    console.log('newWay, age:', age);
    console.log('newWay, fn:', fn);
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I know. Is there a way without argument list? Is there a way with `defaultOptions` object?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use @CertainPerformance's solution for some reason, another option is to destructure after merging with defaults:

```js
function newWay(options?: Partial<Options>) {
    const {name, age, fn}: Options = {...defaultOptions, ...options};
    console.log('newWay, name:', name);
    console.log('newWay, age:', age);
    console.log('newWay, fn:', fn);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM7IDeAUMmciHALYQBcyeYUoA5gNynlwsQD89IAK5UARtA7lkMEP2QAKAJTIAvAD5kABSjYqwPBAA8cEAE9VHAL7FiCXI2QATCPEEAbMBix2VRTmUo09ADkAELYIkEANH7I3HTIAIwAHNGS0vSKKupaOnoQAHRQEHjYrgBuEHKCIE4woBAOCsQWHMQw1QheIBQQAO4A6nAmctiYOPiyGnBQWHCuBp7jeKpKJJK2+GBEARCRsTx70hb0i97KRPmXtXBuHmN2e5f5o114LTEbJa4FrtgsckEQH1BiY9jtaFEKNQIAoJORPqUfn8AUCBkM9nEIRieLCPnZEflfv9AcD0VIQFjybirMRUSDFK06UM5IRwcgAEQAQVcwCQ7IssKAA)

Comment: Thanks I know that.

Comment: I think you'd want `options?: Partial<Options>`, but otherwise this is probably the best way to get the behavior the OP is asking for

Comment: @jcalz Good point, that would allow `name` to be absent. (I actually just learned about `Partial` -- a handy tool!) I've added it to the answer.